# Determining generating function

Tags: probability

> An unbiased coin is tossed n times. If a head appears, +1 is scored; if a tail appears, -1 is scored. The random variable $X$ is the total score obtained. Determine the probabiliy generating function of $X$.
>
> Another unbiased coin is tossed n times. If a head appears, +2 is scored; if a tail appears, -1 is scored. The random variable $Y$ is the total score obtained. Determine the probabiliy generating function of $Y$.

How do I find $G_X(t)$ and $ G_Y(t)$?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you do it for small $n$, like $1, 2$ or $3$, for instance?

Comment: For $n=1$, I know that $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=0.5$ and for $n=2$, $P(X=-2)=P(X=-1)=P(X=0)=P(X=1)=P(X=2)=0.5^2$.

Comment: For $n=2$, you have $P(X=-2)=P(X=2)=0.5^2$ and $P(X=0) = 0.5^2 + 0.5^2 = 0.5$

Comment: Have you heard about [binomial probability](http://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/binomial.aspx)?

Comment: Yeah, but wouldn't the pgf of a binomial distribution that follows $B(n,0.5)$ be $(0.5+0.5t)^n$? Why is it not the answer?

Comment: @user373534 Because the values from a binomial distribution is all the integers from $0$ to $n$ (a failes sample gives $0$ and a successfull sample gives $1$), while in this case the possible values are moved to being every _other_ integer from $-n$ to $n$ ($-1$ for failure, and $1$ for success instead). So you would want $(0.5t^{-1} + 0.5t)^n$.

Comment: @Arthur thank you for your help thus far. the next question I have is how to calculate the mean and variance of this unique distribution without using the generating function formula $E(X)=G'(1)$. manual calculations using the generatng function formulae have led me to finding that the mean is 0 and the variance is $n$, but is there a new formula for this distribution we can use to prove that it is 0 aside from wordy explanations or the formulae?

Comment: Expectation is linear, so the expectation of the entire game is equal to the sum of expectation for each flip. Variance you can steal from the binomial distribution, just remember that because things are twice as spaced out, the variance is four times as high.

Comment: ah, so $E(X)$ is now the sum of expectation from 0 to $n$ and also 0 to $-n$, thus giving $E(X)=np-np=0$, and variance is now $Var(X)=4np(1-p)=n$. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was handled in the comments, but in general if a coin has probability $p$ of heads and $q$ of tails, along with payoff $H$ for heads and $T$ for tails, then the generating function for the value of $n$ flips is
$$
G(t) = (p t^H + q t^T)^n.
$$
As a check, note that $$
G'(t) = n (p t^H + q t^T)^{n-1} (p H t^{H-1} + q T t^{T-1}),
$$
so $G'(1) = n(pH+qT)$ is the expected value of $n$ flips.